# Votantes. São os mais bem votados ou os que mais votaram?

Tags: debate, suporte

Quando listamos os usuários do site. Existem algumas formas de classificar, como por exemplo: 
**reputação:** os que possuem maior reputação aparecem primeiro;
**novos usuários:** lista os usuários recentes que estão em destaque, aqueles que em poucos dias como usuário conquistaram vários pontos de reputação; 
**votantes:** lista os usuário mais bem votados;
 
**editores :** lista os usuário com maior número de edições;
 
**moderadores:** lista os moderadores do site.

Estou com dúvida **votantes**. São os mais bem votados ou os que mais votaram?

Votantes:
Que ou quem vota ou tem direito a votar

"votantes", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/votantes [consultado em 11-04-2016].

Comment: Desculpem a pergunta mas, onde fica a área de listagem de usuários do site?

Comment: @VictorGomes No alto à direita, botão "Usuários". [Link direto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users)

Answer (score 12):

A aba votantes exibe o número de votos dados pelos usuários em um determinado período (semana, mês, etc).

A descrição da aba diz que entram nessa estatística apenas usuários que votaram mais de 10 vezes no período.